# Android fragment null pointer in Run mode, ok in debug

Tags: android, robotium

If I run my unit test in Debug mode,  Eclipse , on an emulator,  it will run fine and complete with no errors.
However if I do it in Run mode it crashes.
Here is my fragment code

```
public class TextAnswerButton extends Fragment
{
...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater,
            final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textanswer, container,
                false);

        answer = (TextAnswer) getArguments().getSerializable("answer");

        final Button button = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button_answer);
        button.setText(answer.getAnswerText());

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                callback.answerQuestion(answer);
            }
        });
        return layout;
    }
}
```

The problem is

```
answer = (TextAnswer) getArguments().getSerializable("answer");
```

answer will be null in Run mode. What is it about the timing that might cause this to be null.  Is it not able to deserialize it quickly enough?

Here is my Robotium test for completeness, simple create activity and click on button.

```
    public void testSelectQuiz() throws Exception {
    SOLO.assertCurrentActivity("Expected QuizListActivity", QuestionActivity.class);
    SOLO.clickOnButton("One");
    //q0.getAnswers().
    //SOLO.cli
}
```

Comment: Can you post logcat of the error please?

Comment: Yeah, errors said much more. Try to use solo.waitForActivity(); before  assertion